# How to find the numbers in a list that come in numerical order in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list, like this:

```
list_1 = [1,2,2,3,1,2]
```

I want to create another nested lists like this:

```
[[1,2,2,1,2],[2,2,3,2]]
```

The first nested list is only composed of 1 and 2 because, according to the numerical order, 2 comes after 1 and 1 is must be included. 3 is not in the first nested list because after 1 comes 2 and not 3.

In the second nested list, there is 2 and 3 because 3 comes after 2 and 2 needs to be included. 1 is not there because one doesn't come after 2.

How can I achieve this in Python 3?

Comment: I'm very confused how you generate these lists.

Comment: `list_1 = [1,2,2,3,1,2]; list_2 = [[1,2,2,1,2],[2,2,3,2]]`. Unless you mean to generate list_2 from list_1 in which case I think you'll need to elaborate on the algorithm to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_1 = [1,2,2,3,1,2]

m = max(list_1)
print([[i for i in list_1 if i in [j,j+1] ] for j in range(1,m)])

#[[1, 2, 2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2]]




#list_1 = [1,2,2,3,1,2,4,2,3,6,5,4]
#->[[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4, 3, 4], [4, 5, 4], [6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can go without a functional one liner, you could do it like this.

```
def listsep(lst, sep):

    l1 = []
    l2 = []

    for v in lst:
        if v <= sep:
            l1.append(v)

        if v >= sep:
            l2.append(v)


    return [l1, l2]

print(listsep([1,2,2,3,1,2], 2))
```

Just iterate the input and append to each list if less than/equal or greater than/equal. This iterates the input only once.